# Is there any way to extend the 'C' drive by shrinking the other volume like 'E'?

Tags: windows-10

[Screenshot in Disk Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWvwa.jpg)There is very little space is left on my C drive but there is about 70 gb unused space on E. So, I want to extend my C drive without any data loss.

Comment: You would have to delete the partition in order to accomplish that

Comment: Use disk management to shrink E and move it to the right. Then you can expand C.

Comment: @SpiderPig : You may be assuming that there is no D: in the middle, stored in between the C: and the E:.  That assumption *could* be true (especially if D: got assigned to an optical drive before a later partition was created), but there's also a rather reasonable possibility of that assumption not being true.

Comment: @SpiderPig  i also tried to shrink E but still 'expand' option is disabled for C except E. Please help what should i do.?

Comment: @Biswa i had provided the screenshot now please help.

Comment: Whatever you do, the Extended Partition (green border) will remain at its position. Windows offers almost no support to deal with Extended Partitions. There is *no* way to solve this using built-in tools only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a way, I do not know if the Windows 10's stock Disk manager will work here but EaseUS Partition Manager will surely work in your case without any data loss.(You'll need Professional version.)
Another approach to the solution is to live boot into a Linux distro(Gparted is recommended) and resize the partitions.(Make sure to completely shutdown Windows as hybrid reboot causes issues while partitioning.)
Drop a message if you are having any problems.

Comment: i don't  want to use any third party application

Comment: @daya: that is not stated in your question. also there are some tasks not doable with built-in applications.

Comment: The use of a Gparted Live Linux stick (e.G. Ubuntu) is the most elegant solution. It is Free Open Source Software, and won't leave any traces on your system. But beware, there is always a risk of data loss and **backups are recommended in any case**, not only partitioning